# How to count and display the number of all files in my account's space with the names starting with g, t and w? UNIX

Tags: unix

Hey guys. I would like to set up the alias in my enviromental file which counts and display the number of all files in my account space with the names starting with g, t and w. So far I came up with something like this:

```
 alias countGTW=find . \( -name 'g*' -o -name 't*' -o -name 'w*' \) | wc -l
```

However it only counts those within the subdirectories of a current working directory. What I want is that it counts them in my WHOLE account's space. I'm using Korn shell. Hope I explained my problem well enough. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by your whole account you mean everything in or below your home directory, replace the `.` with `$HOME`.

Also, you can simplify the `find` considerably since the `-name` predicate understands globbable wildcards:

```
find $HOME -name '[gtw]*' | wc -l
```

Comment: If you use -iname instead of -name you will pick up files starting with G, T, and W as well.